# Java AES file encryption memory issue

Tags: java, encryption, memory-leaks

I am having trouble finding memory leak in encrypting file in java.

The following is the code which increases memory usage of the app and after completing, it doesn't releases the used memory.

```
   while (bytesRead > 0) {
        cout.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        md.update(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        bytesAvailable = fin.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        bytesRead = fin.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        readSoFar += bytesRead;
        cout.flush();

    }
```

If I put System.gc(), which is not recommended, on each iterations, memory doesn't grow.

Comment: Note that there are no guarantees about exactly when garbage collection will occur.  Are you actually seeing memory problems (as in, OutOfMemory exceptions)?  If not, it is probably fine and the JVM will reclaim the memory when it needs it.

Comment: You are right, but when I have big file say in GBs that takes me app's memory into GBs, I haven't see any out of memory issue but the memory usage was more than 4 GB in my 16 GB RAM system. And yes, I waited for few hours but memory never reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do this. Put this code in separate method call. Then call the same method in a loop from a main method.

Meanwhile keep a watch on heap memory usage. You should be able to reach on a high memory occupancy after some good number of iterations (say 1000). Then watch over, if GC is happening or not.

A good symptom of memory leak is that, the used memory keep on surging on an average.